# How can we draw a complex 3D graphics using math tools?

Tags: graphing-functions, 3d

I want to draw a 3D graphics, just as follows:

$z=x^{2}+y^{2}, x=0, y=0, z=0, x+y-1=0$ (it's formed by these surfaces)

What math tool should I use and how can I do it with details?
(I've tried intersected lines but failed)[image]

Comment: This isn't really a math question, but if you are on a mac, try the built-in grapher in utilities.

Comment: Judging from your comments, I think the thing you are looking for is called [Constructive solid geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry).  That keyword may help you narrow down software to meet your particular needs.

Comment: thank you for information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use [CalcPlot3D](https://c3d.libretexts.org/CalcPlot3D/index.html?type=z;z=x%5E2+y%5E2;visible=true;umin=-4;umax=4;vmin=-4;vmax=4;grid=30;format=normal;alpha=-1;constcol=rgb(255,0,0);view=0;contourcolor=red;fixdomain=false;contourplot=true;showcontourplot=false;firstvalue=-1;stepsize=0.2;numlevels=11;list=;xnum=46;ynum=46;show2d=false;hidesurface=false;hidelabels=true;showprojections=false;surfacecontours=true;projectioncolor=rgba(255,0,0,1);showxygrid=false;showxygridonbox=false;showconstraint=false&type=implicit;equation=x+y-1%7E0;cubes=16;visible=true;fixdomain=false;xmin=-4;xmax=4;ymin=-4;ymax=4;zmin=-4;zmax=4;alpha=-1;view=0;format=normal;constcol=rgb(255,0,0)&type=implicit;equation=x%7E0;cubes=16;visible=true;fixdomain=false;xmin=-4;xmax=4;ymin=-4;ymax=4;zmin=-4;zmax=4;alpha=-1;view=0;format=normal;constcol=rgb(255,0,0)&type=implicit;equation=y%7E0;cubes=16;visible=true;fixdomain=false;xmin=-4;xmax=4;ymin=-4;ymax=4;zmin=-4;zmax=4;alpha=-1;view=0;format=normal;constcol=rgb(255,0,0)&type=implicit;equation=z%7E0;cubes=16;visible=true;fixdomain=false;xmin=-4;xmax=4;ymin=-4;ymax=4;zmin=-4;zmax=4;alpha=-1;view=0;format=normal;constcol=rgb(255,0,0)&type=window;hsrmode=3;nomidpts=true;anaglyph=-1;center=-7.249585785953505,5.341349537681467,4.3489643650422725,1;focus=0,0,0,1;up=0.4935642340420161,-0.21247014102594042,0.8433568556945126,1;transparent=false;alpha=140;twoviews=false;unlinkviews=false;axisextension=0.7;xaxislabel=x;yaxislabel=y;zaxislabel=z;edgeson=true;faceson=true;showbox=true;showaxes=true;showticks=true;perspective=true;centerxpercent=0.5;centerypercent=0.5;rotationsteps=30;autospin=true;xygrid=false;yzgrid=false;xzgrid=false;gridsonbox=true;gridplanes=false;gridcolor=rgb(128,128,128);xmin=-4;xmax=4;ymin=-4;ymax=4;zmin=-4;zmax=4;xscale=2;yscale=2;zscale=2;zcmin=-4;zcmax=4;xscalefactor=1;yscalefactor=1;zscalefactor=1;tracemode=0;keep2d=false;zoom=0.416667), which renders this plot:
[image]

If, however, you are interested in the portion of the surface $z = x^2 + y^2$ bounded by the planes, then this is given by

\begin{align*}
z&=x^2 + y^2\\
x&\ge 0\\
y&\ge 0\\
z&\ge 0\\
x+y-1 &\ge 0
\end{align*}

CalcPlot3D can't handle inequalities, although you can do this in [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/3d) using the syntax

`z=If(x+y-1>=0&&x>=0&&y>=0&&x^(2)+y^(2)>=0, x^(2)+y^(2))`

Note that you do need to express the constraint $z\ge 0$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, which is where the condition $x^2 + y^2 \ge 0$ comes from.  This produces the plot:

[image]

Comment: Got it! but how can i dicard the outside to obtain a complete graph? If I want to get a perfect boundary (like in $x=0$ plane, $z<y^2$ )

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're asking for.  The plot contains all the surfaces/planes you specified.  Can you express the region as a set of inequalities? (And update the question as well so others see the distinction).

Comment: I edited my answer to include a plot of what I think you're interested in.

Comment: exactly, you made it, thx!

Answer (score 3):

```
ContourPlot3D[{z - x^2 - y^2 == 0, x == 0, y == 0, z == 0, 
  x + y - 1 == 0}, {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2}, {z, -0.2, 1.2}, 
 ContourStyle -> {Yellow, Magenta, Cyan, Green}, Mesh -> 9]
```

[image]

In  *Mathematica* you can set orthogonal coordinate plot domain limits as desired in  ContourPlot3D.

Comment: thank you too !